# Log into Robinhood using Python Requests Module

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to log into the Robinhood API using:

```
import requests

def login():
   u = "myusername"
   p = "mypassword"
   url = "https://api.robinhood.com/api-token-auth/"   
   r = requests.get(url, username=u, password=p)
   #r = requests.get(url)
   return r.text

print login()
```

I have a way to do it in Curl which is:

```
'curl -v https://api.robinhood.com/api-token-auth/ -H "Accept: application/json" -d "username='+username+'&password='+password+'"'
```

When using Python-requests I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rhood.py", line 12, in <module>
    print login()
  File "rhood.py", line 8, in login
    r = requests.get(url, username=u, password=p)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a dictionary containing the parameters you wish to send with the request (see `data` in the code below).  Then include the dictionary in your request by using the `json` parameter.

Also note, [Robinhood API documentation](https://github.com/sanko/Robinhood/blob/master/Authentication.md) seems to suggest a POST request is required, as opposed to a GET request.  Therefore, the code below uses `requests.post(...)`.

```
import requests

def login():
   u = "myusername"
   p = "mypassword"
   url = "https://api.robinhood.com/api-token-auth/"   
   data = {"username": u, "password": p}
   r = requests.post(url, json=data)
   return r.text

print login()
```

Comment: Although the error went away the login still failed. I will accept the answer.

Comment: Yeah I think the Robinhood API isn't very official and may not be working as advertised. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the authentication modules in the requests library

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/